# Running a Unix Executable Objective-C file in Java (OS X)

Tags: java, unix, terminal

I've seen this question asked before and tried following the solutions posted. Unfortunately, they aren't working. I'm trying to make a simple Java program that can run a compiled Objective-C program (Unix Executable file) with an input parameter. Below are the attempts at Java I have tried that don't seem to be working:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", fullFilePath, Param};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

This is generating a Processor error of 126 for "Command invoked cannot execute". I've tried other variations that don't work as well such as:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash fullFilePath \"Param\""};
String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/open fullFilePath \"Param\""};
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how I can get this to work? I just need to run the compiled Objective-C program in Java with the parameter. I figured it wouldn't be this hard. Thanks in advance, and if you need more information just ask.

Comment: What is the value of fullFilePath ? is it the app folder or the enclosed executable

Comment: This is the full path to the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you're executing your executable through the command line? Being more of a Windows person I might be missing something, but surely just the following should work:

```
String[] cmd = {fullFilePath, Param};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

(assuming `fullFilePath` is indeed the full absolute path to your executable).

BTW: the fact that the other program is written in Objective-C is almost certainly irrelevant.

Comment: Ideally it should, but for some reason the parameter is being ignored when I use that. The program runs (return val of 0) as it should, but the parameter is dropped. I'm really confused why Java is just ignoring the parameter.

Comment: @David: Do you know if the application expects to be run under a certain directory? The reason I ask is that using `exec(cmd)` will run it under the same working directory as your Java process. You might need to look into the `exec(String[] cmdarray,String[] envp,File dir)` overload instead, if that's the issue.

Comment: Got it! Ok so, apparently Java wanted the executable to be in the same directory as the compiled java class file. I really wish this was in the Java documentation for Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @David: it *is* in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29). It's not that Java expects the executable to be in the same directory, it is that by default it runs the executable under the same working directory as your class (subtle distinction). You can alter that behaviour using the overload I linked to. **EDIT:** unfortunately the formatting for the comment has broken the link. Look for the `exec(String[], String[], File)` overload for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sh`:-

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", fullFilePath, Param};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: This generates the return val 126: "Command invoked cannot execute."

Comment: Are you running in Windows or Unix environment?

Comment: Unix. And apologies, the error 126 was on my part. Using your code runs, but the parameter is ignored/dropped.

Comment: @David: I think I know your problem. You need to make your file to be executable in the first place. Use `chmod` to make it executable, then try it again: http://www.xaviermedia.com/documents/chmod755.php

Comment: Great minds think alike! :D Already tried chmod +x and chmod 755. This is really strange. The parameter shouldn't be getting dropped like this...

Comment: What does the `Param` look like? From your snippet, it looks like you are passing a `Param` variable, but what does it contain?

Comment: It's just a string. The problem was Java requiring the executable to be in the same directory as the compiled java class file. Of course, they didn't mention this. I appreciate the help! Annoying how it was something so simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error 126 is "Permission problem or command is not an executable".

Make sure that your file is executable from the command line first. You may have to set the execute bit first using chmod.

```
chmod a+x <filename>
```